# ssh terminal does not autocomplete or store command history

Tags: linux, bash, shell, amazon-web-services

I have a virtual server with ubuntu in AWS. I have created multiple users on my server. When I ssh into the server as the root user (ubuntu), I am able to use the bash auto complete for basic commands and bash history. But when I login as a different user it does not work? Is there anything I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Maybe the other users have `/bin/sh` as their login shell? Try `chsh` in that case.

Comment: `echo $BASH_VERSION` to see whether you're running `bash`.  If you're not, and you want to, and you don't want to change the current user's default shell (which is what `chsh` does), run `bash -l`.  Of course if you *do* want to change the default login shell, `chsh` is the way to do it.

Comment: I checked and I am not running bash. Is there anyway to make my default shell bash? I want to ssh into the server and use bash by default.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Bash Reference Manual, §9.1: Bash History Facilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-History-Facilities):

> When the `-o history` option to the `set` builtin is enabled (see [The Set Builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin)), the shell provides access to the *command history*, the list of commands previously typed.

So, I'd try running

```
set -o history
```

and seeing if that fixes it. If it does, then you'll probably want to add that to the other users' log-in scripts.

(Note that `set -o history` primarily controls whether commands are added to the history, so to test it adequately, you'll want to run:

```
set -o history
echo foo
echo !!
```

to confirm that it prints `echo foo`.)